What is the ploidy of endosperm formed through apomixis
From my limited knowledge, apomixis there is no fertilization. And there is no meiosis either.
So how does the mechanism for this come about and how can we find out the ploidy of the endosperm formed?
The example we got in the text is when a diploid egg cell without meiosis becomes a seed (if that helps).
Are there other kinds of apomixis present?
